# How can i test Facebook webhooks in a development environment?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, webhooks

In my app we have webhooks setup so Facebook notifies us of changes in an ad account.

It looks like you can only set 1 URL for webhooks so i cant remove the production endpoint because that would mess up the production environment.

Is there any way i can send webhooks to another URL?

The only option i can think of is just hardcoding some fake payloads and testing my code that way.

Does anyone know if there is a way to set some type of development endpoint?

EDIT:

For anyone that comes back to this, a test app can never be "live" this means that calls that require an app that is not in development will not work. Maybe the best workaround is to create a duplicate app and get it approved.

[image]

Comment: Create a proper Test App version of your production app, and modify the settings for that one accordingly. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-apps

Comment: @04FS Cant believe i completely missed that. Thanks, you can submit this as the answer if you want, this is exactly what i needed.

Comment: Glad it helps, I added an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook has introduced a feature called Test Apps a while ago.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-apps

You can create a test version of your production app, that will get its own app id, and have its own app dashboard where you can change most of the settings - including webhook endpoints.

Comment: please this is not the solution

Comment: This is not a good solution, it is only a partial solution, because some test events, like leadgen, will send an event with a non-existing resource IDs (like 444444444), which makes it impossible to request additional mock data (to graph api url for ex) for the full test of the process you are developing

Comment: So unless Facebook created a way to test lead ad creation form by connecting to a test app, i don't see this working as needed